# How to list directory folders in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am newbie in rails and wanted to know any way to list folders and files for a url say public . So example user types example.com/public  he gets all folders and files listed as we do in php if we start a wamp server . I need this so I can create files and have their url shared to public i.e. simply send url link online like example.com/public/test.pdf . Currently I am getting page with no routes defined .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epbgs.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a controller to serve the file using a route parameter, ex.

```
get '/public/:filename', to: 'file#serve'
```

Then use the `send_file` method in your controller.

```
class FileController < ApplicationController
    def serve
        # For authorization:
        #authorize!

        # For authentication: (a way or another)
        #redirect_to :access_denied unless user_signed_in?

        send_file "/www/yourapp/var/files/#{params[:filename]}"
    end
end
```

This way the file can be anywhere within your app, or even on a Cloud storage. It also gives you the ability to use authentication or authorization to check if the user has access.

**Please note that this code is very simple, but there are much more options like Fog gem for Cloud storage and everything else.**

See https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file for more information.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer but i just want to make whole public directory accesible . So user can just type example.com/public and see all folders and files like we get on mozilla ftp https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Comment: @zack There are some methods in Ruby which you can use to list files then show them in a ERB page. This way you can implement a more sophisticated design.

Comment: Thanks I came across method to loop direcory and files. I was just checking if there was any rails method to list directories and folders but unfortunately there is not I guess :) .

Comment: @zack Not in Rails, but Ruby as it built-in. Using `Dir` class if my memory serves.